# understand behavior of sqrt - giving different results when written different

Tags: python, pandas, null, series, sqrt

I have pandas series that has the following numbers:

```
0   -1.309176
1   -1.226239
2   -1.339079
3   -1.298509
...
```

I'm trying to calculate the square root of each number in the series.

when I tried the whole series:

```
s**0.5
>>>
0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4       NaN
         ..
10778   NaN
```

but if I take the numbers it works:

```
-1.309176**0.5
```

I also tried to slice the numbers from the series:

```
b1[0]**0.5
>>>
nan
```

**So i'm trying to understand why it works when I write number but doesn't work when I use the series**

*the values are float  type :

```
s.dtype
>>>dtype('float64')

s.to_frame().info()
>>>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10783 entries, 0 to 10782
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   B1      10783 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 84.4 KB
```

Comment: What is `s.to_frame().info()` ? It seems same data related problem.

Comment: It's about operator precedence. [This](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity) may help.

Comment: Are you sure your series has a numerical datatype? What does `s.dtype` show?

Comment: @jezrael added in the post

Comment: The fist is trying to take the square root of a negative number,  the second takes the square root of a positive number and makes it negative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't take a square root of a negative number (without venturing to complex numbers).

```
>>> np.sqrt(-1.30)
<stdin>:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
nan
```

When you do `-1.309176**0.5`, you're actually doing `-(1.309176 ** 0.5)`, which is valid.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with operator precedence in python. Precedence of `**` > unary operator `-`.

The square root of a negative number should be complex number. but when you compute  `-1.309176**0.5`, it first computes the `1.309176**0.5` and then takes minus of it because the precedence of `**` is > `-`.

```
>>>1.309176**0.5
-1.144192291531454

>>> (-1.309176)**0.5
(7.006157137165352e-17+1.144192291531454j)
```

Now numbers in your series are already negative, it's not like you are doing the unary operation `-` on them hence the square root of theses numbers should be complex number which Series shows as `nan` because the dtype is `float`.

```
>>> s = pd.Series([-1.30, -1.22])
>>> s
0   -1.30
1   -1.22
dtype: float64
```

Square root of this series gives `nan`.

```
>>> s**0.5
0   NaN
1   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Change `dtype` to `np.complex`

```
>>> s = s.astype(np.complex)
>>> s
0   -1.300000+0.000000j
1   -1.220000+0.000000j
dtype: complex128
```

Now you get the square root of s.

```
>>> s**0.05
0    1.000730+0.158500j
1    0.997557+0.157998j
dtype: complex128
```